# How to set Timeouts in Selenium/standalone-chrome in gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: selenium, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-image

How can be setted timeouts (-timeout -browserTimeout) in gitlab-ci.yml for selenium server if I use selenium/standalone-chrome image?

[Selenium Timeout Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/ko/documentation/legacy/remote_webdriver_server/#timeouts-from-version-221)

Below piece of my gitlab-ci.yml

```
marked_test:
  image:  $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
  allow_failure: true
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
      alias: chrome
    - name: selenium/standalone-firefox:latest
      alias: firefox
  only:
    refs:
      - main
    variables:
      - $TAG_RUN == "marked"
  tags:
    - run01_docker
  script:
    - $PYRUN -m $TAG_MARK --env="$TEST_ENV" --mode="server" --browser=$TEST_BROWSER --alluredir=$ALLURE_RESULTS_FOLDER 
      fi
  timeout: 2h
```

I searched the Internet for a solution to this kind of problem, I tried to solve it with what I found but nothing could help

For example:

```
  services:
    - name: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
      alias: chrome
    environment:
      SE_OPTS: "-timeout 86400 -browserTimeout 86400"
```

Answer (score 2):

I use circleci and also met the issue, the problem is - selenium node is terminating in default 300 seconds, to extend this time I used this and it helped me: (f.e. 11k seconds)

- image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
  environment:
  SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT: 11000